# Testing Adobe Air App for iPhone

Tags: iphone, adobe, air

how can I deploy my prototype app in order to test it on my iphone? obviously it isn't at the stage where it can go on the app store but I;d like to play about with it for testing..

Do I HAVE to enrol in the developer program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be enrolled in the Apple Developer Program to receive a certificate you can use to sign your apps to be installed on your iDevice.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. But you knew that.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I disagree. It's an answer to a yes or no question.

Answer (score 0):

Although we as a developer don't suggest illegal installation, but some developers may find it is actually easier with the dark method:

Install you iPhone or iPad with "Installous" and "iFile",
with iFile, you can open a wifi port for any computer in the same wifi network to access the machine from there browser and upload file to the machines (without using iTune), so you can put your *.ipa file in the machine.

In order to manually install the ipa file, you may want to use the Installous, so what someone will do is to put the ipa to the [root]/mobile/Documents/Installous/Downloads, then when you open up Installous, go to Downloads, you will see your ipa and be able to install it!

Hope this hope.